# Positioning tables using CSS

Tags: html, css

Assume I have three simple tables. How do I make the tables be inline horizontally (instead of vertical) while only using css? I can do it using a table, however I am trying to learn css better and I would like to do it using css if possible. I realize that may involve adding a div tag or something and that is ok, I just do not want to use a table (for learning purposes).

Just to be sure I am clear what I want.... currently the tables display like this:

```
table
table
table
```

but I want the tables to display like this:

```
table table table
```

Here is some html with three tables [and a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Nv4e/) to get us started.

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>
<body>
<h3>table one</h3>
<table border=1>
<tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
<tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
</table>

<h3>table two</h3>
<table border=1>
<tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
<tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
</table>

<h3>table three</h3>
<table border=1>
<tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
<tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help everyone. float:left works. Now i'm trying to figure out how to do something like this:

```
table table
table table
```

Comment: You generally shouldn't avoid tables when representing any table (horizontal or vertical, it doesn't really matter) data. On the other side, you must use divisions and spans (which are semantically raw HTML elements) to markup any other, non-table data (except lists, for sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
display: inline-block;
```

or

```
float: left;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `h3` tags are getting in the way if you do this:

```
table {display: inline-block;}
```

You have an option putting the `h3` and `table` sets in `div`s and then align the `div`s, or replace `h3`s with `caption`s.

Answer (score 1):

just wrap a  with the 'float' style set to left on each table:

something like this...

```
<div style="float:left><table></table></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may float elements in order to display them inline. For example, if you want to display your `h3` and `table` elements in one row you could use this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      div {
        float: left;
        width: 20em;
        margin: 1em;
        background-color: green;
      }

     table {
       width: 100%;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div> 
      <h3>table one</h3>
      <table border=1>
      <tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
      <tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
      <tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
      </table>
   </div>

   ...

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A code only with tables and css

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
table
{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<table border=1>
<tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
<tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
</table>


<table border=1>
<tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
<tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
</table>


<table border=1>
<tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
<tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A code only with HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>

<table border=1>
<tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
<tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
</table>

</td>
<td>

<table border=1>
<tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
<tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
</table>

</td>
<td>

<table border=1>
<tr><th>field1</th><th>field2</th></tr>
<tr><td>data</th><th>bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>whooo</th><th>foo</td></tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>

</body>
</html>
```